# How to compute a type that is in T and U but not in both

Tags: typescript

I want to compute a type that is a subtype of type T and U but not both for example

```
type Exclude<1|2|3,2|3|4> //<1,4>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, kind of an [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator. You can do that like this:

```
type A = 1 | 2 | 3;
type B = 2 | 3 | 4;
type result = Exclude<A | B, A & B> // result is 1 | 4
```

Or to make a reusable utility type:

```
type XOR<T, U> = Exclude<T | U, T & U>
type result = XOR<A, B>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UCMUA+UBMaoGYDcAsAFCiRQBCCm2O2ALISeNABpUCiAHgMYA2ArgBMIAHjjpyAGlhQAZBQB8xYqVYB5AEoiAKtICqCjjwHCd2PdO1yoB5UzIssiFprHTyCoA)